# Получить источник обращения к файлу php

Tags: php

Есть файл Php, который подключается на сторонние сайты и выдает изображение.

```html
<img src="http://site.ru/file.php" alt="">
```

В гугле ничего подходящего так и не нашел. Есть ли возможность узнать, откуда идет обращение к файлу?  Т.е. отображается в теге img на сайте или человек перешел напрямую по ссылке (ведь фактически в img тоже, как напрямую заход).  Открытие изображения в соседней вкладе тоже необходимо отлавливать.  В общем цель, чтоб при обращении к данному файлу, он (файл) внутри себя понимал обращение идет со страницы где он вставлен в тег img и он будет возвращать изображение туда же или к нему обращаются из вне (открытие изображения в соседней вкладке / переход по ссылке напрямую).  Пробовал отлавливать заголовки и в том числе реферера (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`), но не дает нужных результатов (в том числе отсутствует кросбраузерность, а она нужна).

Comment: Что у вас не получилось с `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`? Если запрос идет со страницы, то в этой переменно будет значение этой самой страницы, если открывается напрямую - то никакого значения не будет

Comment: @YuriyProkopets не всегда. есть атрибут `no-referrer`, но это уже проблемы вставляющего. в целом тоже не понял, чем не удружил `http_referer`

Comment: Тем, что если открыть изображение в новой вкладке, то там так же передается сайт, а мне надо разграничивать, то что на самом сайте и то что открыто напрямую в браузере. Мне не важно с какого сайта важно что в данный момент в браузере. Страница где только изображение или сайт где вставлено изображение.

Comment: кажется, у нас для вас плохие новости (: но вообще загружайте изображение через js передавая доп. заголовки/параметры в запросе, это наверное единственный путь.

Comment: js не вариант. но я так и думал, что выхода в моей ситуации нет ((

Comment: Браузер может посылать разные Accept заголовки для img и просто ссылки. Но это тоже на его усмотрение